# Why does Eclipse remember MySQL databases/tables after they've been deleted from /var/lib/mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, maven, ubuntu

Using Ubuntu 15.04, Eclipse Mars and JDBC MySQL Connector. Testing a Web Service (Maven project) that, upon deployment, builds several databases and tables. On first test, built just fine - thus, no code posted because there are no errors of syntax.

Before second test, however, I deleted all db directories under `/var/lib/mysql`. On running second test, Eclipse gives me an error stating that my tables can't be created because they already exist. Tried forcing reload of `/etc/init.d/mysql`, clearing query cache, as well as "`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`table`;`" before issuing the `CREATE TABLE` query. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I deleted all db directories under /var/lib/mysql.

Don't do that.

The correct way to remove a database is to `DROP DATABASE foo;`.  Tinkering with the files in `/var/lib/mysql` requires that you Know Exactly What You're Doing™.

What you have probably done is left tables stranded in the data dictionary.

What you probably can do is recreate the database manually with `CREATE DATABASE foo;` then try dropping it.  Failing that, you may need to (from the shell, not from mysql) `sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql/foo` then `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/foo` and *then* try `DROP DATABASE foo;`.  Failing that, restart the server and see if it is any happier after that if you try to drop the database once again.

Note that if you are not using the MySQL command line client, you should run the query `SHOW WARNINGS;` after each query above -- some clients do not tell you when warnings occur and they can contain useful troubleshooting info.

Also, `SELECT @@ERROR_LOG;`.  Read the log file on your server at the path indicated.